# verbose_name for a model's method

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

How can I set a verbose_name for a model's method, so that it might be displayed in the admin's change_view form?

example:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(....)
    def created_weekday(self):
        return self.created_date.strftime("%A")
```

in admin.py:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('created_weekday',)
    fields = ('title', 'created_weekday')
```

Now the label for created_weekday is "Created Weekday", but I'd like it to have a different label which should be i18nable using ugettext_lazy as well.

I've tried

```
    created_weekday.verbose_name=...
```

after the method, but that did not show any result. Is there a decorator or something I can use, so I could make my own "verbose_name" / "label" / whateverthename is?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[list_display](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

```
created_weekday.short_description = 'Foo'
```

This solution requires the method to be defined in the ModelAdmin class. You can call a Model method (eg: `get_created_weekday`) from ModelAdmin like:

```
def created_weekday(self, obj):
    return obj.get_created_weekday()
```

Comment: thanks, that works. no wonder I didn't find it in the documentation - it is written under "ModelAdmin.list_display"...

Comment: Yes, but the documentation for `readonly_fields` does say "This option behaves nearly identical to ModelAdmin.list_display".